# Vertically Stacked Y-Axis Step Line in Live Charts WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, livecharts, scichart

I've been using Winforms and the built in Charting library to accomplish this task in a hacky sort of way, but the team I'm developing for wants a more interactive solution. I wish I was able to just stack several charts, but as the graph is representative of a digital timing diagram, they need to share the same x-axis. I'm looking at LiveCharts as a solution, but I can't figure out if it's possible to vertically stack the multiple y-axis items to achieve my end goal. Ideally, it would look like this:

[image]

It's very important that I maintain them as one chart so that they share the x-axis, and comparisons can be made within the same chart timing wise.

The data getting used is from a generated log file, and is not collected in real time. I would manually offset the data, but the user can choose the order in which the graphed lines are displayed, so I would have to go through the entire series and offset it each time the user moved it.

Perhaps livecharts is not the way to go here? It needs to be a free implementation of something, or SciCharts v2.2 (but I can't find archived documentation) as those are the only resources I currently have access to.

Comment: This scenario is currently not supported in LiveCharts, the good news is that v1 is coming, it is a full rewrite of the library, I hope this is finally supported soon.

Answer (score 0):

While your question doesn't specifically relate to SciChart, you have tagged it, so I have a suggestion for you.

There is a [vertically stacked axis feature](https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart-example-vertically-stacked-yaxis/) in SciChart WPF. This allows you to substitute the YAxis Container template for anything you want. In this example we use a UniformGrid. The result is as follows:

[image]

Several traces are on the same plot, but at different vertical positions. Each axis is stacked one over each other. They share the same XAxis and hence response to zooming, panning, tooltips as if they were one chart.

The source code to the above is on the [Example Webpage](https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart-example-vertically-stacked-yaxis/). All the scichart WPF Examples source code is hosted on GitHub so if you click through to the above then scroll down to source and click 'View on Github' you can see how we have achieved this type of chart.

**Disclosure to community: Im the tech lead on the SciChart project**

Comment: I have in fact seen this! Unfortunately, as far as I am aware (relevant devs are currently away on vacation) the company I'm interning at and making this internal tool only has SciChart v2.2 licensed (as mentioned at the bottom of my post). This older version seems to be missing the relevant AxesPanelTemplate properties in the SciChartSurface that I would need to use to implement that solution (based on the example). I'm not greatly familiar with WPF or SciChart yet, so I'd be eager to find out if my problems are on the way to being solved with that example after all!

Comment: Yes this feature AxesPanelTemplate was added in version 4 I’m afraid. It is not possible to achieve this functionality with v2.  SciChart had loads of offers to upgrade to the latest version at half price if you’re a previous customer but they expire December 31st 2017...

Comment: Sad to hear, but thanks for the heads up anyway! Unfortunately I don't think a little internal tool written by an intern is cause enough for them to jump on updating their license, and even if it was, the staff who would make that decision aren't back until after the date anyway. :) Thanks again!